# When do trinkets apply their passive effects?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

[image]

When do trinkets apply their passive effects in Orcs Must Die 2? Do you need to have it selected or does it apply the passive as long as it is in your trap menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The passive effects are always applied, as long as that trinket is in your inventory.

You can test this by choosing the mana trinket - your maximum mana goes up immediately.